# how to query mongoose based on OR condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have a transaction collection and i require to query this from mongoose

```
    _id: 5ecba0d446d0354084ad0b89
    amount: 3
    userId: 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765
    type: 4
    userType: 1
    recipientId: 5ec328f2c7762963c88db768
    status: "succeeded"
    createdAt: 2020-05-25T10:41:24.449+00:00
    updatedAt: 2020-05-25T10:41:24.449+00:00
    __v: 0


    _id: 5ecba0d446d0354084ad0b92
    amount: 4
    userId: 5ec3285cc7762963c88db888
    type: 4
    userType: 1
    recipientId: 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765
    status: "succeeded"
    createdAt: 2020-05-25T10:41:24.449+00:00
    updatedAt: 2020-05-25T10:41:24.449+00:00
    __v: 0


    _id: 5ecba0d446d0354084ad0b97
    amount: 8
    userId: 5ec3285cc7762963c88db332
    type: 4
    userType: 1
    recipientId: 5ec328f2c7762963c88db589
    status: "succeeded"
    createdAt: 2020-05-25T10:41:24.449+00:00
    updatedAt: 2020-05-25T10:41:24.449+00:00
    __v: 0
```

how to query this such that i can get the transactions based on following condition

```
userId = 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765 or recipientId = 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765
and type = 4
and userType = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) and [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) operators

```
model.find({
   $or: [ 
     { userId: 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765 },
     { recipientId: 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765 }
   ],
   $and: [ { type: 4 }, { userType: 1 } ]
});
```

Comment: and how can i populate the other id for example userId matches with 5ec3285cc7762963c88db765, then i want to get name and profile pic of the recipientid and vice versa.